# Select the next span element after an HTML element Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to select the next `span` element with a class name `slider-value` after a selected HTML element. I've tried multiple solutions, but none of them works.

I could select it by `id`, but I don't wish to do it that way to make the code redundant.

```js
$('.slider').change(function() {
  var slider = this;
  var output = $(this).closest('div').find('.slider-value').first();
  output.innerHTML = slider.value;
  slider.oninput = function() {
    output.innerHTML = this.value;
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="col-md-3">
  <span class="slider-text">Total Monthly Income</span>
  <input type="range" min="1" max="100" value="50" class="slider" id="salary">
  <span class="slider-value"></span>
</div>
```

Comment: ‍‍`output` is a jQuery object. Setting the object's `innerHTML` property has no effect. You need to use the jQuery `html`method for modifying the `innerHTML` property.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`output` is a jQuery object and has no `innerHTML` property. To update the content of the element use `text()` instead. `html()` would also work, but not necessary here as you're only updating it with a string value.

In the following example note that I used the `$` prefix on variable names to denote they contain a jQuery object. I also used the `input` event instead of `change` so that the value is updated immediately.

```js
$('.slider').on('input', function() {
  var $slider = $(this);
  var $output = $slider.closest('div').find('.slider-value').first();
  $output.text($slider.val());
}).trigger('input');
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="col-md-3">
  <span class="slider-text">Total Monthly Income</span>
  <input type="range" min="1" max="100" value="50" class="slider" id="salary">
  <span class="slider-value"></span>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

**You can do as below** with the use of `siblings()` + `text()` OR `html()`

```js
$('.slider').change(function() {
    var slider = this;
    var output = $(this).closest('div').find('.slider-value').first();
    
    $(this).siblings('.slider-value').text(slider.value);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="col-md-3">
      <span class="slider-text">Total Monthly Income</span>
      <input type="range" min="1" max="100" value="50" class="slider" id="salary">
      <span class="slider-value"></span>
</div>
```